# How do I implement one-to-many & many-to-many relationships in my GraphQL schema?

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

This is my first time using GraphQL, and I've created a schema for an app that has Users, Songs, and Tips. Note that both listeners & artists are represented as a User, and that any User can 'tip' a Song by Creating a tip

I'm having trouble correctly defining the one-to-many & many-to-many relationships in the schema. I'm also confused about how to write mutations for creating Song/User/Tip objects that correctly point to one another.

I know I need to use the @connection directive in my schema definition and I've tried following [this example](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/graphql#usage-3), but I'm still confused on how to translate this design to my use case.

Here's a stab I took at specifying relationships between objects:

```
type Song @model{
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  artist: String!
  artistArray: [User]! @connection(name: "SongArtists")
  tips: [Tip]! @connection(name: "SongTips")
  totalAmountReceived: Float!
}

type Tip @model{
  id: ID!
  from: User! @connection(name: "UserTipsSent")
  to: User! @connection(name: "UserTipsReceived")
  song: Song! @connection(name: "SongTips")
  amount: Float!
  createdAt: String!
  hash: String!
}

type User @model{
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  walletAddress: String!
  totalAmountDonated: Float!
  totalAmountReceived: Float!
  songs: [Song]! @connection(name: "SongArtists")
  tipsSent: [Tip]! @connection(name: "UserTipsSent")
  tipsReceived: [Tip]! @connection(name: "UserTipsReceived")
}
```

### My schema without specifying any connections

```
type Song @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  artist: String!
  artistArray: [User]!
  tips: [Tip]!
  totalAmountReceived: Float!
}

type Tip @model {
  id: ID!
  from: User!
  to: User!
  song: Song!
  amount: Float!
  createdAt: String!
  hash: String!
}

type User @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  walletAddress: String!
  totalAmountDonated: Float!
  totalAmountReceived: Float!
  songs: [Song]!
  tipsSent: [Tip]!
  tipsReceived: [Tip]!
}
```

### I want to implement the following relationships

- A Tip must be associated with one Song, a 'from' User and a 'to' User
- A Song must have at least one artist (User)
- A User may have many Songs
- A User may have sent and/or received many Tips

I also don't know how I would write a mutation that (for example) creates a Song (pointing to the correct artist(s)/User(s)) while ensuring the artist (songs array in User object) also references the Song I just created.

It's worth noting that I've created 3 tables in my AWS AppySync DynamoDB (Song, User, Tip), and would like to be able to retrieve (for example) a User, all the Songs they've made, and all the Tips they've ever received in a single query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### My current solution:

GraphQL doesn't natively support many-to-many relationships yet. I simplified my schema (not ideal but making it work for the time being) to ditch the M2M relationships and added a keyField to my connections. Example:

```
type Song @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  artist: String!
  artistObject: User! @connection(name: "ArtistSong", keyField: "userId")
  tips: [Tip]! @connection(name: "SongTip", sortField: "createdAt")
  totalAmountReceived: Float!
  inRotation: Boolean!
}

type User @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  walletAddress: String!
  totalAmountDonated: Float!
  totalAmountReceived: Float!
  songs: [Song]! @connection(name: "ArtistSong", keyField: "userId")
  tipsSent: [Tip]! @connection(name: "FromUserTip")
  tipsReceived: [Tip]! @connection(name: "ToUserTip")
  email: String
}
```

Now, a Song must have only one artist (User). I haven't implemented the connection for Tips yet, but it is working for Users & Songs.

I created Songs linked to their respective User objects by using a field in my mutation called `songArtistObjectId` (referring to the `artistObject` field on my Song model).

Here is the mutation I used (assuming the User/artist has already been created and you have their ID):

```
mutation CreateSong {
  createSong(input: { 
    title: "Ghost", 
    artist: "quickly, quickly",
    songArtistObjectId: "e412ca8a-367c-4cda-bc6f-91aa2d85c180",
    totalAmountReceived: 0,
    inRotation: true
  }) {
    id
    title
    artist
    artistObject {
      id
      name
      walletAddress
    }
  }
}
```

If you're also using AWS Amplify/AppSync, after updating your schema locally be sure to push your changes to the cloud via the Amplify CLI:

```
amplify api gql-compile
amplify push
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any other questions  (:

Comment: While creating the song, how do you also add the Tips? That's what I REALLY need to know. Do you have an attribute songTipIds and pass in an array of Ids? How does it work?